# Bitcoin mining vs Ethereum mining, How does it differ?

Tags: mining

I have understood how Bitcoin mining is done and what exactly the miner solves during the mining process and adding a new block on bitcoin blockchain, I failed to get any information on what ethereum miners have to solve in order to mine ether and create a new block to be added to ethereum blockchain, please share a link or details if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is well documented it took me all of 2 seconds to google.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining

> Introduction The word mining originates in the context of the gold
>   analogy for crypto currencies. Gold or precious metals are scarce, so
>   are digital tokens, and the only way to increase the total volume is
>   through mining it. This is appropriate to the extent that in Ethereum
>   too, the only mode of issuance post launch is via the mining. Unlike
>   these examples however, mining is also the way to secure the network
>   by creating, verifying, publishing and propagating blocks in the
>   blockchain.
>
> Mining Ether = Securing the network = verify computation So what is
>   mining anyway? Ethereum Frontier, like all blockchain technologies
>   uses an incentive-driven model of security. Consensus is based on
>   choosing the block with the highest total difficulty. Miners produce
>   blocks which the others check for validity. Among other
>   well-formedness criteria, a block is only valid if it contains proof
>   of work (PoW) of a given difficulty. Note that in Ethereum 1.1, this
>   is likely going to be replaced by a proof of stake model.
>
> The proof of work algorithm used is called Ethash (a modified version
>   of Dagger-Hashimoto) involves finding a nonce input to the algorithm
>   so that the result is below a certain threshold depending on the
>   difficulty. The point in PoW algorithms is that there is no better
>   strategy to find such a nonce than enumerating the possibilities while
>   verification of a solution is trivial and cheap. If outputs have a
>   uniform distribution, then we can guarantee that on average the time
>   needed to find a nonce depends on the difficulty threshold, making it
>   possible to control the time of finding a new block just by
>   manipulating difficulty.
>
> The difficulty dynamically adjusts so that on average one block is
>   produced by the entire network every 12 seconds (ie., 12 s block
>   time). This heartbeat basically punctuates the synchronisation of
>   system state and guarantees that maintaining a fork (to allow double
>   spend) or rewriting history is impossible unless the attacker
>   possesses more than half of the network mining power (so called 51%
>   attack).
>
> Any node participating in the network can be a miner and their
>   expected revenue from mining will be directly proportional to their
>   (relative) mining power or hashrate, ie., number of nonces tried per
>   second normalised by the total hashrate of the network.
>
> Ethash PoW is memory hard, making it basically ASIC resistant. This
>   means that calculating the PoW requires choosing subsets of a fixed
>   resource dependent on the nonce and block header. This resource (a few
>   gigabyte size data) is called a DAG. The DAG is totally different
>   every 30000 blocks (a 100 hour window, called an epoch) and takes a
>   while to generate. Since the DAG only depends on block height, it can
>   be pregenerated but if its not, the client need to wait the end of
>   this process to produce a block. Until clients actually precache dags
>   ahead of time the network may experience a massive block delay on each
>   epoch transition. Note that the DAG does not need to be generated for
>   verifying the PoW essentially allowing for verification with both low
>   CPU and small memory.
>
> As a special case, when you start up your node from scratch, mining
>   will only start once the DAG is built for the current epoch.
>
> Mining Rewards Note that mining 'real' Ether will start with the
>   Frontier release. On the Olympics testnet, the Frontier pre-release,
>   the ether mined have no value (but see Olympic rewards).
>
> The successful PoW miner of the winning block receives:
>
> A static block reward for the 'winning' block, consisting of exactly
>   3.0 Ether All of the gas expended within the block, that is, all the gas consumed by the execution of all the transactions in the block
>   submitted by the winning miner is compensated for by the senders. The
>   gascost incurred is credited to the miner's account as part of the
>   consensus protocol. Over time, it's expected these will dwarf the
>   static block reward. An extra reward for including Uncles as part of
>   the block, in the form of an extra 1/32 per Uncle included Uncles are
>   stale blocks, ie with parent that are ancestors (max 6 blocks back) of
>   the including block. Valid uncles are rewarded in order to neutralise
>   the effect of network lag on the dispersion of mining rewards, thereby
>   increasing security. Uncles included in a block formed by the
>   successful PoW miner receive 7/8 of the static block reward = 2.625
>   ether A maximum of 2 uncles allowed per block.
>
> Ethash DAG Ethash uses a DAG (directed acyclic graph) for the proof of
>   work algorithm, this is generated for each epoch, i.e every 30000
>   blocks (100 hours). The DAG takes a long time to generate. If clients
>   only generate it on demand, you may see a long wait at each epoch
>   transition before the first block of the new epoch is found. However,
>   the DAG only depends on block number, so it CAN and SHOULD be
>   calculated in advance to avoid long wait at each epoch transition.
>   geth implements automatic DAG generation and maintains two DAGS at a
>   time for smooth epoch transitions. Automatic DAG generation is turned
>   on and off when mining is controlled from the console. It is also
>   turned on by default if geth is launched with the --mine option. Note
>   that clients share a DAG resource, so if you are running multiple
>   instances of any client, make sure automatic dag generation is
>   switched on in at most one client.
>
> To generate the DAG for an arbitrary epoch:
>
> geth makedag   For instance geth makedag
>   360000 ~/.ethash. Note that ethash uses ~/.ethash (Mac/Linux) or
>   ~/AppData/Ethash (Windows) for the DAG so that it can shared between
>   clients.
>
> The Algorithm Our algorithm, Ethash (previously known as
>   Dagger-Hashimoto), is based around the provision of a large,
>   transient, randomly generated dataset which forms a DAG (the
>   Dagger-part), and attempting to solve a particular constraint on it,
>   partly determined through a block's header-hash.
>
> It is designed to hash a fast verifiability time within a slow
>   CPU-only environment, yet provide vast speed-ups for mining when
>   provided with a large amount of memory with high-bandwidth. The large
>   memory requirements mean that large-scale miners get comparatively
>   little super-linear benefit. The high bandwidth requirement means that
>   a speed-up from piling on many super-fast processing units sharing the
>   same memory gives little benefit over a single unit.

Here is the algorithm with code examples

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash